# Training with BatchNorm in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm wondering if I need to do anything special when training with BatchNorm in pytorch. From my understanding the `gamma` and `beta` parameters are updated with gradients as would normally be done by an optimizer. However, the mean and variance of the batches are updated slowly using momentum.

1. So do we need to specify to the optimizer when the mean and variance parameters are updated, or does pytorch automatically take care of this?
2. Is there a way to access the mean and variance of the BN layer so that I can make sure it was changing while I trained the model.

If needed here is my model and training procedure:

```py
def bn_drop_lin(n_in:int, n_out:int, bn:bool=True, p:float=0.):
    "Sequence of batchnorm (if `bn`), dropout (with `p`) and linear (`n_in`,`n_out`) layers followed by `actn`."
    layers = [nn.BatchNorm1d(n_in)] if bn else []
    if p != 0: layers.append(nn.Dropout(p))
    layers.append(nn.Linear(n_in, n_out))

    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, i, o, h=()):
        super().__init__()

        nodes = (i,) + h + (o,)
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([bn_drop_lin(i,o, p=0.5) 
                                     for i, o in zip(nodes[:-1], nodes[1:])])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
        for layer in self.layers[:-1]:
            x = F.relu(layer(x))

        return self.layers[-1](x)
```

Training:

```py
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
    # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
    inputs, labels = data

    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward + backward + optimize
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Batchnorm layers behave differently depending on if the model is in train or eval mode.

When `net` is in train mode (i.e. after calling `net.train()`) the batch norm layers contained in `net` will use batch statistics along with gamma and beta parameters to scale and translate each mini-batch. The running mean and variance will also be adjusted while in train mode. These updates to running mean and variance occur **during the forward pass** (when `net(inputs)` is called). The gamma and beta parameters are like any other pytorch parameter and are updated only once `optimizer.step()` is called.

When `net` is in eval mode (`net.eval()`) batch norm uses the historical running mean and running variance computed during training to scale and translate samples.

You can check the batch norm layers running mean and variance by displaying the layers `running_mean` and `running_var` members to ensure batch norm is updating them as expected. The learnable gamma and beta parameters can be accessed by displaying the `weight` and `bias` members of a batch norm layer respectively.

**Edit**

Below is a simple demonstration code showing that `running_mean` is updated during forward. Observe that it is not updated by the optimizer.

```
>>> import torch
>>> import torch.nn as nn
>>> layer = nn.BatchNorm1d(5)
>>> layer.train()
>>> layer.running_mean
tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> result = layer(torch.randn(5,5))
>>> layer.running_mean
tensor([ 0.0271,  0.0152, -0.0403, -0.0703, -0.0056])
```

Comment: Just to reiterate, is it the optimizer that takes care of updating `running_mean`, `running_var` using batch statistics? If you know, could you also point out to where in the code it does this? Otherwise a simple yes or no to the first question would suffice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @sachinruk The optimizer doesn't update the running statistics, it does update the gamma and beta parameters. The demo code I added shows that the running statistics are updated during a forward pass. I believe the update is actually applied [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/3185b455c6bf54219a5cb69644248f888d075474/aten/src/ATen/native/Normalization.cpp#L218) in the code for the CPU version. It's a bit difficult to follow the entire code flow however.